# How to make an array after an "if" statement is passed?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, printing, syntax

```
def main():
    print(f'[{datetime.now()}] => getting listing ids[]')
    response = requests.get('api', params=params, cookies=cookies, headers=headers)
    
    response_data_ids = response.json()
    
    listing_ids = [result['id'] for result in response_data_ids['results']]

    
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] => got listing ids[{response.status_code}]')
    else:
        print(f'error getting listing ids[{response.status_code}][{response}]')

    for i in range(len(listing_ids)):
        response = requests.get(f'api{listing_ids[i]}/pr', cookies=cookies, headers=headers) 
        response_price = response.json()
        
    
        price = response_price['priceCents']
        id = response_price['product']['id']
        item = response_price['product']['name']
        lowest_ask = response_price['lowestPriceCents']
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] => Current Price: {price/100:.2f} | Lowest Price: {lowest_ask/100:.2f} | ID: {id} | Item: {item}')
        
        
        over_priced = []
        for x in over_priced:
            if price > lowest_ask:
                over_priced.append(x)
                print(over_priced)
        print(f'[{datetime.now()}] => over lowest ask[{price/100:.2f}][{id}]')

main()
```

I got my code working where it got the 1st request then compiles to an array which is then used for a new get request, iterating through each value printing a new piece of data within that response but I have it working(currently) where it would print all items that are `price > lowest_ask`, but I want to save those item IDs in price in potentially a nested list? (id, price) but I want another another deduction also which would be `lowest_ask - 100`.

How could I make this all work? When I run the code I also am getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'` when I change stuff around.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It's not clear what your code is meant to be doing. `for x in over_priced: over_priced.append(x)` is a tautology; "for each thing in my list add that thing to my list". As to the question " i want to compile those printed IDS into an array": create an array `my_ids=[]` outside of any loop, then inside the loop `append()` the value you want into the array. It would help to see a sample of your input and expected output based on that input to make a [mcve]

Comment: Edited with full code

Comment: I had the array outside the loop and append() within also but how it works is each value in the first array then gets a new value that I want to then group to a new array

Comment: im so close to finishing my first *full* program haha. everytime ive used stackoverflow or just trying python i get stuck but my code is working now and im trying to figure this out

Comment: There are a number of questions in here, but to start with: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'` means that in one of your iterations, you are getting `None` for a variable which you are then trying to divide by an int (so likely `price` or `lowest_ask` is coming back as `None` at some point)

Comment: so how could I combat the `None` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like a dictionary is the data structure you want. Just declare it outside the loop, and then add to it within the loop (note that this assumes a unique ID in each iteration, otherwise the keys will be overwritten, in which case you would need to use the commented-out list option)

```
my_ids={}
#or my_ids=[]
for i in range(len(listing_ids)):
        response = requests.get(f'api{listing_ids[i]}/pr', cookies=cookies, headers=headers) 
        response_price = response.json()
        
    
        price = response_price['priceCents']
        id = response_price['product']['id']
        item = response_price['product']['name']
        lowest_ask = response_price['lowestPriceCents']

        if price and lowest_ask:
            if price > lowest_ask:
                my_ids[id]=[lowest_ask-100]#could be expanded with additional items to add
                #or my_ids.append([id,lowest_ask-100])
        else:
            print(price, lowest_ask)
```

Comment: I get the error `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'`

Comment: Check the output of `response` with a `print`, an `if` or a `try...except` block. Unfortunately because we can't access the API for you we can't tell you why your attempt to `get` something from it is returning one or more null values

Comment: I just checked and no value `None` was spit out. How would I format the if try except block? edit: used a different json value from the api and it works now

Comment: In the error you provided, `lowest_ask` was clearly `None`, as that's what the error is saying, but I've edited to show one possible example

Comment: Yea I fixed it but my next question is if I wanted to bundle the `price` with the `lowest_ask` say in a nested list and then I wanted to make another post request with the first item in each bundle being used in the payload and 2nd in a request url. how could i format this now? I got it so it subtracts the values ready to be posted but I want to bundle the corresponding IDS. Which I have already printed

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. What have you tried? For example: `for id,ask in my_ids.items():request.get(id)...`? Or instead of printing the items as you have, append to the external dict or list and call it from there?

Comment: I want to bundle the prices with the listing ID with a nested loop? after `if price > lowest_ask:` because from then I want to use those 2 ids in a json for a post request how would i go about that then.